# url redirect according to visitor ip

Tags: jquery

I want the url redirect according to visitor's ip, and I have the below code, tested but it is always going to AU, all other else if conditions not working, please help and many thanks...

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="Javascript"> 
    var mylocation=geoplugin_countryCode();
    if (mylocation=="AU") {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/AU/search-to-buy'},
    else if (mylocation=="CA") {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/CA/search-to-buy'},
    else if (mylocation=="CN") {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/CN/search-to-buy'},
    else if (mylocation=="NZ") {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/NZ/search-to-buy'},
    else if (mylocation=="RU") {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/RU/search-to-buy'},
    else if (mylocation=="US") {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/US/search-to-buy'},
    else if {
    window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/network'},
</script>
```

Comment: redirection like this is much better suited for the serverside, before the page and scripts load. Have you tried this with a computer outside AU to test it, and checked what your geoplugin actually returns by console logging it? Also, you have syntax errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your if-statements - looks like you need to take the comma out of your else-if's and replace with a semicolon:

```
if (mylocation=="AU") {
window.location.href='http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/AU/search-to-buy';
} else if (mylocation=="CA") { ...
```

Comment: Also, get rid of the commas at the end of the lines and use semicolons.